# Connect to Windows Phone 8 Emulator remotely with full support in Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I think this is a straightforward question but I'm looking for someone who has actually tried this and can say yea/nay.

I want to run the Windows Phone 8 emulator on another Hyper-V host than the Visual Studio machine, and connect to it as a debugging device. It would be similar to connecting to a "real" phone in that it's not a local VM, but would obviously not be through a local USB connection.

Do the development tools for Windows Phone 8 support this scenario?

Comment: questions about developing for Windows Phone belong on StackOverflow.com - this is for questions about using the phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do the development tools for Windows Phone 8 support this scenario?

No, this is not supported in the public SDK.